# Mount /mnt/d in bash for Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows-10, bash, mount

I see my drives (c, d, e, g, h) in `bash` for Windows 10 under `/mnt` but when I use `df -h` I don't see them. I'd like to mount these directories to other directories in `/` and give them specific names so that they show up in `df`. For example, I'd like `c` to show up as `/flash1` and `d` to show up as `/flash2`. How can I do this in Windows 10 so that they show up in `df -h`?